# Emacs Xembed, but for HTML

Tags: html, emacs

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXembed, which lets one embed GTK+ widgets in an emacs buffer.

Does anything like this exist that will let me embed HTML "web components" (an encapsulated set of HTML, CSS, and JS) in the emacs buffer, or failing that, just plain old HTML?

Comment: surf, the WebKit-based web browser by the peeps at suckless.org supports XEmbed, maybe you can use it to achieve what you want? https://surf.suckless.org/